# Moving label and input to same line as previous

Tags: css

How can I get the second label and input to be on the same line as the first, while preserving the first label's width, and the top padding?

Code below or here's the jsfiddle version http://jsfiddle.net/kpBNB/2

```
<div>
  <li id="input1">
    <label>From</label>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1 am</option>
    </select>
  </li>

  <li id="input2">
    <label> until</label>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1 am</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</div>
```

---

```
div {
  width: 100%;
   background-color: #ccc;
}

li {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

label {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the width on the `label` you have to add a width to the `li` (as width is determined by the parent element). So something like this ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpBNB/9/)):

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

li {
  width: 30%;   /*this needs width*/
  padding-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  width: 50%; /* since my li was 30% width of ul, 
                 50% of that is back to your original 15% width */
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `<div>` should be an `<ul>` (you can't have loose `<li>` elements outside `<ul>` or `<ol>`).

Then, giving `display: inline-block;` to `li` on your CSS should do the trick.

**Edit**: hey, your jsfiddle already does that, and it works!

Comment: Oops, I didn't update the jsfiddle before posting - here's the updated http://jsfiddle.net/kpBNB/2/ -- In the initial jsfiddle link the label width isn't used, and I need it to be.

Comment: @99miles You don't need to float the labels, just make the `<li>`s `inline-block` as you had in the first version. Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/kpBNB/10/